# Convert VB.NET MDI Application to Non-MDI?

Tags: vb.net, mdi

I have inherited a VB.NET project from a departed coworker.  I have *zero* experience with VB, .NET, or VB.NET, I am a JS developer so this is all Greek to me.

My supervisor would like me to remove the "MDI-ness" of the application.  I.e. we are looking at MDImain.vb and in the previous application (pre-conversion) there is no MDImain.  This project was converted from VB6 to VB.NET and we are struggling to get things working again; the supe's opinion is that eliminating the MDI-ness of the application will help straighten it out.  **So the question is:** is there a straightforward way of making an MDI VB.NET application into a non-MDI one?

Note: I have seen other similar threads with people recommending that the application simply be rewritten from scratch.  I wholeheartedly agree, and would like to do that, but our manager refuses this option as it he believes it will take too long.

Note from comments: the original application was not MDI, this can be confirmed, for example, by running the existing executable and seeing that it is not an MDI application.  The VB6-to-VB.NET conversion in VS 2008 somehow made the old VB6 application into an MDI application without asking.  (I have shadowed a more recent conversion attempt and seen that adding MDI functionality is not part of the process as we encountered it.)  We are trying to figure out how to either prevent this MDI addition in another conversion attempt, or to undo it in the result, since we did not want it.

Comment: MDI is Multiple documents application, which mean you can open multiple documents in one instance of application. but what you mean by _non-MDI_?

Comment: As mentioned, the previous version of the application did not have an MDImain.vb file, and we do not understand why one exists now.  Do all VB.NET applications have this file?

Comment: I Assume by vb.net application you mean Winforms application. If so, Winforms application should have one main(or parent) form, which will be main form of application, by closing which application will closes as well. Name of the file has no affect on it responsibilities, what mdimain.vb file contains?

Comment: It contains a lot of code that was apparently generated automatically by the VB6 conversion.  We do not understand all of it at all.  Perhaps I am asking wrong questions.  I am lost, to the point I do not know what to ask.

Comment: I don't know what *pre-conversion* means, because you've not explained how any *conversion* has been done. What *previous application*? What *conversion* process resulted in the MDImain.vb magically appearing?

Comment: Converting from VB6 to VB.NET using VS 2008, which has the capability to perform this conversion, appears to have created this file.

Comment: Find 'Main" method in your application, and check what form is used to start application the line can look like `Application.Run(someMainForm)` or -ish

Comment: That information should have been in your question. With that being said, MDI is designed for one main (MDI parent) window to act as a container for multiple MDI child windows which are embedded. In order to change that, you have to redesign the app to have the MDI child windows be SDI (single document interface), which means implementing a whole lot of new behavior that doesn't exist. One example: MDI children usually use the parent window's menu for functionality. It's not just flipping a switch to turn off. For that reason, this question is far too broad in scope.

Comment: So the gist of this is, the remaining team members don't understand an MDI WinForms application, so the solution is to rip out all the MDI code - which isn't even understood to begin with - and expects success? Reminds me of when my dad built a 10-speed bicycle without the instructions, and had all these parts left over.......

Answer (score 1):

Your Main Mdi Form has a property called  IsMdiContainer     That is why it is MDI to the operating system.  Change that.    That form should be like this    Search for   `MyApplication    OnCreateMainForm()`     that is where the app "starts"     look at that form to see its IsMdiContainer property.

The other detail is that where you have code that creates and spawns new forms you will have to be aware of the 3 different form display concepts that change when going from MDI to single forms.

```
Public Sub CodeInForm1()
    Dim frm As Form
    frm = New Form2()

    ' Code Concepts for VB Parent Child in MDI and Non MDI scenarios 
    frm.MdiParent = Me   ' MDI Concept
    frm.Owner = Me    ' No MDI but still linked 
    frm.Show(Me)  ' Anoter way to link Forms when spawning a new one (No MDI)
    frm.Show()  ' No Specific Parent Assigned 

End Sub
```

The other thing to be aware of is that the Active Menu concept changes between MDI and separate forms.

If you try these changes do them on a copy of the code.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have said so far, it sounds like your VB6 application had an MDI main form (possibly named Main.frm).
This is used as a 'container' to allow the display of child forms (and also somewhere for the menu).

If you have the VB6 IDE installed (Visual Studio 6) you can confirm this.

If this is the case, removing the "MDI-ness" will change the whole concept of any converted code and create more work for you.

Comment: See question update for more info on this.